# Substract years from current_date in JPQL

Tags: java, jpql

I want to delete the rows which are older than 2 years. In SQL I do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE creation_date < (current_date - interval '2 year');
```

Now I want to do the same for my JPA Repository in Java with the JPQL.
In JPQL I get an error because interval is not known and the "-"(minus) is not correct.

JPQL Query

```
@Query("DELETE FROM table t WHERE t.creation_date <  (current_date - interval '2 year')")
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Why just not use native query? AFAIK JPQL does not give you that option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463143/spring-data-jpa-query-with-the-date-minus-2-days-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the dateTime in the application, assuming you are using `LocalDateTime` for `creation_date`

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().minus(Period.ofYears(2));
```

and pass the parameter in JPQL

```
@Query("DELETE FROM table t WHERE t.creation_date < :dateTime")
void deleteByDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime)
```