# How to use MySQL date function in jpql and hql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

such as

```
date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
```

i find a solution
[Hql / jpql date arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813973/hql-jpql-date-arithmetic)
but there is no following

Comment: Is your question the same with that purpose? My understanding is his question is about to compare the dates in where condition, while your question is about how to sub 7 days.

Comment: same as it,i just want know how to do date calculate in hql

Comment: I added my answer here, hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813973/hql-jpql-date-arithmetic/68152225#68152225

Comment: I have to accept the fact that there is no perfect solution. If you want to map dto conveniently, you have to give up MySQL date function

Comment: Yes, to use the power of built in function of MySQL, let's use `native query`. For customization, use constructor instead. For data mapping, you can use  `ModelMapper` also. And with `DateTime` from MySQL, I usually create some helper to convert the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that directly in HQL/JPQL. You have to register a custom SQL function that renders this SQL.